# jQuery each - binding to all elements instead of single

Tags: javascript, jquery

Playing with some jQuery bits and pieces, I can't seem to get it quite right.
What I'm looking to do is loop through the items on a page, and apply a custom click handler to them. This way when I populate the page I just need to fill out the correct ID and the jQuery can automate filling in the link.

The problem I have is both events are firing with the same output, and I can't work out why. I have 2  which I am using as buttons,

```
<img id="LightButton11Of" src="images/lightbulb_off.png" style="width:32px;
height:32px; vertical-align:middle " alt="off" > 
<img id="LightButton11On" src="images/lightbulb_on.png" style="width:32px;
height:32px; vertical-align:middle" alt="on">
```

and the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[id^=LightButton]").each(function(i,item){
    if ($(this).attr('id').substr(13,2)=="On"){lightfunction="1";}
    if ($(this).attr('id').substr(13,2)=="Of"){lightfunction="0";}
    alert($(this).attr('id').substr(13,2));
    numLight = $(this).attr('id').substr(11,2);
    strLight = "*1*" + lightfunction + "*" + numLight + "##";

    teststr = $(item).attr('id') + " - " + strLight;        
    alert(teststr);

    $(this).bind("click",function(){
        SendEvent("OWN","18",strLight,"OK");
    });
}); 
});
```

The alert(teststr) gives exactly the output I'm expecting, but it seems when I'm binding it is actually binding to all elements and not just the singular item from that iteration of the each loop.

What am I doing wrong!?

Cheers,

Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What am I doing wrong!?*

Your variables are all global.

This code in the click handler:

```
SendEvent("OWN","18",strLight,"OK");
```

...refers to the *global* variable `strLight`, which will have the value set in the last iteration of your `.each()` loop.

You should declare all of your variables with `var`, which will make them local to the function, so then each of the click handlers will use the local variable from its containing scope. (Which, thanks to the "magic" of closures, will still exist even though your each callback will have finished by the time the click events occur.)

```
$("[id^=LightButton]").each(function(i,item){
    var lightfunction = this.id.substr(13,2)=="On" ? "1" : "0";
    var numLight = this.id.substr(11,2);
    var strLight = "*1*" + lightfunction + "*" + numLight + "##";

    $(this).bind("click",function(){
        SendEvent("OWN","18",strLight,"OK");
    });
});
```

(Note also that there's no need to use `$(this).attr('id')` when `this.id` gives you the same value in a way that is faster to type, read and execute, and it's neater to set the value of `lightfunction` using a ternary operator instead of two `if` statements.)

Comment: Perfect :) I originally had the entire string created without any variables at all and had made the problem worse by introducing globals for testing, now I can get back into it!

Comment: I would recommend that you always declare all variables with `var`, even for global variables (declared by using `var` outside of any functions). That way it is always clear what scope variables are supposed to have, and it's clear that you've created globals on purpose rather than by accidentally leaving `var` out within a function.